# Join two files on Linux

Tags: linux, bash, join

I have two files; I want to join them.

```
$cat t1
 1 1.2
 2 2.2
$cat t2
 1
 2
 1
```

I want to have the output below

```
$cat joind.txt
 1 1.2
 2 2.2
 1 1.2
```

but when I use the `join` command, the third line does not appear in the output.

Comment: Does t1 and t2 have a leading whitespace?

Comment: thanks, no it's a big file. I made it easy for understanding. but if I can do this example that will work too.

Comment: How big? That will make a difference if it is 100s of megs.

Comment: no it's less than 100s megs

Comment: The input files to `join` must both be sorted on the joining column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`join`](http://ss64.com/bash/join.html) requires that both files to be sorted. If you sort them first, you'll get all your output

```
$ sort t1 > t1.sorted
$ sort t2 > t2.sorted
$ join -j1 -o 1.1,1.2 t1.sorted t2.sorted
1 1.2
1 1.2
2 2.2
```

Without the sort:

```
$ join -j1 -o 1.1,1.2 t1 t2
1 1.2
2 2.2
```

This assumes that the order of your inputs don't need to be preserved; if they do, you will need a custom script like other answers have provided.

Answer (score 4):

A simple `awk` is suffice for this:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} {print $1, a[$1]}' t1 t2
1 1.2
2 2.2
1 1.2
```

**Breakup:**

```
NR == FNR {                  # While processing the first file
  a[$1] = $2                 # store the second field by the first
  next                       # move to next record in 1st file
}
{                            # while processing the second file
  print $1, a[$1]            # print $1 and the remembered
                             # value from the first file.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following with do:

```
$ while IFS= read -r line; do grep -m 1 "^$line" t1; done <t2
 1 1.2
 2 2.2
 1 1.2
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you want to match the first column of `t1` with the values in `t2`. So `t1` is a dictionnary and `t2` the wanted keys.

If so, you can use this:

```
$ cat t2 | xargs -n1 -I{} grep -P "^\Q{}\E\s+" t1
```

How does it work?

`xargs` will execute the command `grep` for each one entry `-n1` of `t2`. The `-I{}` allows me to put the value where I want to.

Then I execute `grep` which match the wanted value from the dictionary using a regular expression.

```
^    # Any line that begin with
\Q   # Quote the value (in case we have special chars inside it)
{}   # The corresponding value matched by xargs
\E   # End of quoting
\s+  # Followed by one or more spaces (alternatively we can use `\b`)
.*   # Followed by anything (optional)

t1   # Inside the file `t1`
```

Alternatively you can play with Perl :)

```
cat t2 | perl -e '$_ = qx{cat $ARGV[0]}; \
      $t1{$1} = $2 while(/^(\w+)\s+(.*)/gm); \
      print "$t1{$_}\n" for (split "\n", do{local $/, <STDIN>})' t1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try `AWK`:

`awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2}NR>FNR{print $1,a[$1]}' t1 t2`

Comment: Maybe you can edit the answer to explain how is that command working, so that it is understandable even for someone not familiar with `awk`.

Comment: I agree. AWK syntax can be very confusing for newcommers, so some additional comments would be helpful.