# How to merge two files in linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have two files I'm trying to join/merge based on columns .

Example

File 1

```
aa
bb
aa
bb
cc
aa
```

File 2

```
aa 12e
bb wqq
```

Desired output

```
aa 12e
bb wqq
aa 12e
bb wqq
cc
aa 12e
```

Comment: Do you have any approach?

Comment: maybe a dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31097908/join-two-files-on-linux?rq=1

Comment: answerd in this post using AWK 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33268892/using-awk-to-lookup-data-in-2-csv-files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approach using associative arrays in Bash.

First, File 2 is read, and an associative array is constructed, mapping the values:

```
declare -A mapping

while read line; do
    values=($line)
    mapping[${values[0]}]=${values[1]}
done < b.txt
```

Then, File 1 is read, and each entry is looked up, and added to the printed output:

```
while read line; do
    echo $line ${mapping[$line]}
done < a.txt
```

This yields the desired output:

```
aa 12e
bb wqq
aa 12e
bb wqq
cc
aa 12e
```

I feel like there has got to be a more compact way to do this in a few lines with some old UNIX-era tools, too. Perhaps someone will enlighten us.

Comment: Tnx Jameson
But i dont want remove duplicate record & sort

Comment: What? You do or do not? The code above does what you asked for.

Comment: Ok, I don't want to remove duplicates. and the results are sorted...

Comment: Okay, so do the above, and then pipe it into sort. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html

Comment: Your first code result is :
    aa 12e
    bb wqq

Comment: You are running it with File 1 and File 2 backwards. Reverse them, and it works. You have to actually follow what I said for it to work.

Comment: Its Work - Tnx Jameson

Answer (score 1):

```
join -a 1 <(sort file1) <(sort -k1,1 file2)
```

Output:

```
aa 12e
aa 12e
aa 12e
bb wqq
bb wqq
cc
```

Drawback: You loose order of file1.

Comment: Tnx Cyrus
Its fine
But it would be better if had not sorted